# Getting the depth of a point in a bitmap

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, photo

I would like to get the "depth" (distance) of a point in a bitmap.
For example, if there are 2 items in a photo, i want to know which of them has bigger depth, means which of them is more far away.

As an image has RGB, does it also have some depth data?
or is there another way to know the depth?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know which point is further away from the camera?

Comment: yes, that will be a good point to start with.
after i do that, i will want to know the exact distance of the point from the camera.

Comment: By which means was the bitmap created, and how would the sensor used be able to capture that depth information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to directly obtain depth information from a bitmap. A bitmap holds so called "color depth" that is nothing more than color information. The amount of information a Bitmap can hold ranges from 1 bit (black and white) upt to 32 bit (RGB) per pixel.

This website provides a very good reference to Bitmaps: [A Beginners Guide to Bitmaps](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bitmaps/)

But still it is not impossible to calculate depth information from an regular image format / Bitmap. Different approaches have been developed to solve the task of depth estimation such as [Saxena et al., 2007](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/learningdepth/ijcv_monocular3dreconstruction.pdf)

This however is a challenging task based on hierarchical, multi-scale [Markov Random Field (MRF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field) holding so called [images features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_(computer_vision)) that can be used to solve the task of estimating the depth relation between different objects (points) in an image. On their [website](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/learningdepth/) you'll find more examples of their work and links to further readings.

Answer (score 0):

Usual image formats don't store depth information as usual cameras don't capture that. If you have stereo photos, you might take a look at what's called spatial reconstruction.